# How to retrieve data from a hardcoded website?

Tags: json, rest, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application for Android and iOS in Xamarin.Forms, and I need to put some content in the application. The content needs to be the same as from a hardcoded website i.e. I don't have a RESTful API. The only source I have is what I can get from the Chrome DevTools Elements panel.

I am using Realm as my database.

My question is; what is the best way to work with this problem? I thought about, somehow, putting the data manually in my Realm database and then retrieve it from there, as a JSON object, to the application.

Comment: This is called screen scraping.  Use a package like AngleSharp to load the website and parse the HTML so you can extract the content.

Comment: it's screen scraping, but i think that if the website is not yours, it's not legal to do it ...

Comment: Not sure about the legality, but it's definitely against many websites' terms of use.